# How to read all the values inside an multiple form with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to get my uploading script to work with jQuery but having problems with fetching the values (files) that are queued up in a multiple form.

I can get it to work so I can select like 10 files in a single input but when I'm trying to fetch those values I only get the first file of the 10 I added simultaneously. I can upload the files and fetch its values but I want to make it to work with jQuery as well something I can't get to work.

Here is the code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en-us">
 <head>
 <script src="jquery-min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("form").change(function() {
     var form =  $(".forms").val();
      $(".files").append("Files:"+form);
   });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" class="forms" value="" name="upload[]" multiple>
    <button type="submit">Upload!</button>
</form>
<div class="files"></div>
<?php var_dump($_FILES);?>
</body>
</html>
```

So when I drag and select the files and adds them then only the first value gets assigned to "div.files". So my question is how do i read the array of the files inside of it so I just don't get the first one?

Here is an image that displays the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOAvk.png

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a jQuery uploader plug-in like: [Upoadify](http://www.uploadify.com/).  It has a nice UI out-of-the-box w/ a progress bar and probably offers a better API for your code above.  Here's an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('#file_upload').uploadify({
        'uploader'      : '/path/to/uploadify.swf',
        'script'        : '/path/to/uploadify.php',
        'cancelImg'     : '/path/to/cancel.png',
        'folder'        : '/uploads',
        'onAllComplete' : function(event,data) {
          document.getElementByID('someForm').submit();
        }
      });
    });
</script>
<form id="someForm" action="someFile.php" method="post">
<input name="someField" type="text" />
<input id="someID" name="someName" type="file" />
<input onclick="$('#someID').uploadifyUpload()" type="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried that but it's still not working correctly (Its flashscript still got bugs in it) and i don't have time to wait for the v 3.0 for my application. Thanks for the quick answer tough.